# iPhone simulator not working since xcode5 upgrade

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode5

Ever since i upgraded to xcode5, the iOS simulator only displays as an iPad even though the project is targeted for iPhone. The Run button also shows it's set to iPhone and I've tried switching between the different iPhone types in simulator. But no matter what, my iPhone project opens as an iPad simulation. Anybody encounter this problem or know how to fix it?

I believe I've downloaded all the relevant libraries and tools from apple as well. I'll double check that now but I'm pretty sure I have all the accessory downloads up to date.

*Edit*

I found the answer! Due to the changes with resolution of the retina display, the simulator was loading without the bezel. Turns out the best way to solve this problem without a large screen or retina display is to deploy target in navigator=>General menu=> to iOS 6.1 and make sure iOS simulator=>Hardware=>Devices=>is set to iOS 6.1 as well.

Comment: Go to xcode preference and check out downloads.

Comment: Got them all except iOS 5.0 simulator

Comment: If you found the answer then add a new answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the simulator device? Go to iOS Simulaotr.app -> hardware -> devices?

Comment: Yes it's one of the first things I looked at.  It's strange because I'm looking at an iPad simulator while the device is set to iPhone.

Comment: Thats strange, whenever it happened to me I did what I suggested you to do.

Comment: Completely strange! I can't make heads or tails of it. Not sure if I need to reinstall Xcode if that would help at all or not.

Answer (score 0):

Download the extra components/simulators..

[image]

[image]

Comment: As I've mentioned above, I downloaded all those components as well. I did go double check and the only one I didn't bother with was iOS 5.0 Simulator. I have all the others.  But still no iPhone simulator on my screen. When I was using Xcode 4.*, I always had the iPhone simulator working. Only when I upgraded to Xcode 5 I got this problem. And still no fix :(

Answer (score 0):

If you find your iOS simulator is showing a large iPad like display since upgrading, it's because of the change in resolution for the retina display. In order to view the simulator as a regular looking iPhone follow these steps:

1. Deploy your project target for iOS 6.1 or earlier. In the navigator menu (far left), top folder (your project folder), click it. Make sure "General" is selected in the menu in the centre of the screen. In 'deployment Info' set it to iOS 6.1 and 'devices' to iPhone.
2. Open iOS simulator: Click 'XCODE' in the top left of the screen => Open Developer Tools => iOS Simulator.
3. In iOS simulator, go to => Hardware => Devices => select iPhone => iOS 6.1.  Make sure not to select any of the hardware devices that are listed as retina displays, thats the major key.
4. Finally, make sure the deployment next to the run button is also showing 'iPhone iOS 6.1' AND NOT 'iPhone Retina...'

And enjoy seeing the iPhone simulator properly again! :)